# How to reproduce ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected through Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: sql, oracle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Through Jenkins pipeline, if I get error `ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected`, I want to perform some action.

FOr testing I should get that message. If I create user and log in with it to sql developer and try to drop it through pipeline it results into above error -

```
sh '''
   sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
   connect system/system@orcl
   DROP USER TEST_USER;
   exit
   EOF
'''
```

Is there any way I can connect using that user and drop it through pipeline so results into above error?

Comment: do you want to drop the user anyway ? or you want to get the error  ? sorry but I don't understand what is exactly what you want. You can't drop a user which is connected. You need to kill the sessions of that user before drop it

Comment: I want to get that message and based on that I'll perform different actions in pipeline.

Comment: you can get the return code of the error. It is ok for you ?? If so, I will provide you an answer

Comment: Yes that will also work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running that part through a PIPELINE in Jenkins using shell script, there are some options:

**Get a specific Return Code of the Operation**

In this case, you might do the following

```
sh '''
   sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
   connect system/system@orcl
   whenever sqlerror exit 99
   DROP USER TEST_USER;
   exit
   EOF
'''
```

This operation will return 99 in case you got the error. You must evaluate the the return of the operation using `$?`

Example

Session 1 ( as system )

```
SQL> create user test identified by Oracle_1 ;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to test ;

Grant succeeded.
```

I connect with the user test, and then with my system user I will try to drop it

```
SQL> whenever sqlerror exit 99
SQL> drop user test ;
drop user test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected


Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64                                                                 bit Production
[ftpcpl@scglvdoracp0040 ~]$ echo $?
99
```

**Using PLSQL Block to return code or message**

However, if you want something different than the option before, like having the code displayed automatically without evaluation, then you can get the message display by the output using an anonymous PL/SQL block.

In your case, I would use something like this:

```
sh '''
   sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
   connect system/system@orcl
   set serveroutput on feedback off
   declare
   user_is_conn exception;
   verror varchar2(100);
   pragma exception_init ( user_is_conn , -1940 );
   begin
       execute immediate q'[ DROP USER TEST ]';
       exception 
       when user_is_conn then 
          verror := sqlerrm ; -- the whole error message
          -- verror := sqlcode ; -- only the  code 1940
          dbms_output.put_line(verror); -- message 
       when others then 
          raise;
   end;
   /       
   exit
   EOF
'''
```

I commented `verror := sqlcode` in the section before to show the whole message. An example of this running in Linux would be:

```
$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" << eof
set serveroutput on feedback off
   declare
   user_is_conn exception;
   verror varchar2(100);
   pragma exception_init ( user_is_conn , -1940 );
   begin
   execute immediate 'DROP USER TEST' ;
   exception
   when user_is_conn then
      verror := sqlerrm ;
              dbms_output.put_line(verror);
           when others then
              raise;
   end;
/
eof
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
```

Be aware that this PL/SQL block is ended OK. I mean, from OS perspective the operation return code is 0. If you want that as a error, you need to raise the error, but in that case the message would be different.